# How to generate a JSON schema of a model that include another model in C#

Tags: c#, json, schema

I am using Json.NET Schema to generate schema from a model. 
I am ok when validating :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace HomeAddressSearch
{
    public class Properties
    {
        [Required]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "civic_number")]
        public string CivicNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "postal_code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "city_name")]
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I use the following and pass the JSON for validation to the output schema :

```
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();

JSchema outputSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(Properties));
```

I don't know what to do when I want to validate JSON on the model Place that includes the model Properties :

```
namespace HomeAddressSearch
{
    public class Place
    {
        public Place()
        {
            Properties = new Properties();
            PlaceType = new List<string>();
        }

        [Required]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "place_type")]
        public List<string> PlaceType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "properties")]
        public Properties Properties { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was only a mistake in my validation now evrything works